# Distance between 2 points with CLLocationCoordinate2D

Tags: ios, ios7, core-location, cllocationmanager

## Details

I'm trying to measure the distance between two coordinates on a map (longitude, latitude).  The first coordinate is my **current location** which is a `CLLocation`, and the other one is a pin on the map which is of type  `CLLocationCoordinate2D`.

## Issue

I call `distanceFromLocation` to get my current location in `CLLocation` but it says bad receiver type from `CLLocationCoordinate2D`.

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D locationCoordinate;

// Set the latitude and longitude
locationCoordinate.latitude  = [[item objectForKey:@"lat"] doubleValue];
locationCoordinate.longitude = [[item objectForKey:@"lng"] doubleValue];

CLLocationDistance dist = [locationCoordinate distanceFromLocation:locationManager.location.coordinate]; // bad receiver type from CLLocationCoordinate2D
```

### Question

I want to find the distance between these 2 coordinates in metric unit, and I know that types are mismatching, but how to convert them so I can find the distance between these 2 nodes?

Comment: The distanceFromLocation method is in the _CLLocation class_ and it takes a _CLLocation object_ as a parameter (not a _CLLocationCoordinate2D struct_).  That's what the error means.

Comment: Yes I know why I was getting this error, but I didn't know how to convert it to make it work!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the below method for finding distance between two locations

```
-(float)kilometersfromPlace:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)from andToPlace:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)to  {

    CLLocation *userloc = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:from.latitude longitude:from.longitude];
    CLLocation *dest = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:to.latitude longitude:to.longitude];

    CLLocationDistance dist = [userloc distanceFromLocation:dest]/1000;

    //NSLog(@"%f",dist);
    NSString *distance = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",dist];

    return [distance floatValue];

}
```

Comment: Actually is better to return a double since the result of `distanceFromLocation` is a a CLLocationDistance which is indeed a double.

Answer (score 6):

For example:

```
   +(double)distanceFromPoint:(double)lat lng:(double)lng
   {

      CLLocation *placeLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:lat longitude:lng];
      CLLocationCoordinate2D usrLocation = locationManager.location;
      CLLocation * userLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:usrLocation.latitude longitude:usrLocation.longitude];

      double meters = [userLocation distanceFromLocation:placeLocation];

      return meters;
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to convert `CLLocationCoordinate2D` to `CLLocation`,

Create a `CLLocation` object using,

```
-(id)initWithLatitude:(CLLocationDegrees)latitude longitude:(CLLocationDegrees)longitude
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on @manujmv's answer above, here's a Swift extension (returns metres):

```
import Foundation
import CoreLocation

extension CLLocationCoordinate2D {
    func distanceTo(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> CLLocationDistance {
        let thisLocation = CLLocation(latitude: self.latitude, longitude: self.longitude)
        let otherLocation = CLLocation(latitude: coordinate.latitude, longitude: coordinate.longitude)

        return thisLocation.distanceFromLocation(otherLocation)
    }
}
```